# Yii: loading css and js files when calling another controller

Tags: yii

In my html code I'm calling another controller like this:

```
<a class='objName' href='".CController::createUrl('/mobilechart/index')."'>$dd->name</a>
```

When this controller is loaded it doesn't charge the css and js files, I can see the content but not in the correct style or correct working, but if I refresh the page it does it. Why is this happening?

I'm not sure if this helps but also the first time it charges (when css and js files are not loaded) the "yii-debug-toolbar-switcher" is working and when the page is properly loaded it doesn't!

I load the css and js files using:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `CController::createUrl('/mobilechart/index')` doesn't actually load a controller, it just creates a url to the specified controller/action. You're not actually calling another controller. Also, where exactly are you registering the CSS and JS files? It would also help if you could explain a bit what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have two different controllers and in some point I need to make a user interaction between both of them. I have added a link between them but I'm not able to do it right! I am loading the files in the layout. Any suggestion? I'm quite new to yii and may be I'm missing some concept!

Comment: What do you mean by "user interaction"? Do you want your user to navigate from one action to another through hyperlinks or do you want to call an action from another controller when you are rendering the view? Which one is the controller that needs the Javascript? I can't really figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I wan't the user to be able to navigate between both views, not just a  function is another controller to change controller. Does is makes any sense??

Comment: May be is better to use the same controller and just change the view (layout), if this is the case I have no idea how o do it! thx!

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that after you click the link that you've generated in one view, you're seeing it rendered w/o style sheets and/or layout?  And the code you've added about the css and js is in the second view?

Comment: No, I can see the layouts but the js and css files are missing, if I refresh they work perfectly... thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for the link:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::link(
    $dd->name,
    array( '/mobilechart/index' ),
    array( 'class' => 'objName' )
);
?>
```

Also, make sure that both your controllers are using the same layout. Or if they're using different layouts, make sure that you register the CSS and script files in both layouts.

Comment: It does exactly the same thing! It changes the screen properly but t doesn't load the css files properly!

Comment: Ok, then it would be great if you could post your layout code. Are you using AJAX loading in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Register client script, css in Yii](http://www.codexamples.com/98/how-to-include-javascript-css-in-yii/)